# Row belongs to another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to transfer data row from one local datatable to another. But i receive an error that stated:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: This row already belongs to another table.

My code:

```
        DataTable missedQueue = new DataTable();
        DataSet queue = DBMgr.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM queue");

        DataRow dr = queue.Tables[0].NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < queue.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dr[queue.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName] = queue.Tables[0].Rows[0][i];
        }

        missedQueue.Rows.Add(dr); // error shown here
```

However after i researched and changed the code to

```
       missedQueue.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
```

It says that "*Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.*"

Comment: The error is caused by the fact that the missedQueue table has no schema. It is just an empty datatable whitout any column. You need to Clone the source table (if you want to just copy the first row) or use the Copy method if you want to copy the whole table in the new table.

Comment: @Steve i have already originally created the table missedQueue, and the columns are the exact same as the queue table.

Comment: The how do you explain the error message?

Comment: Try to check with the debugger the value of Columns.Count in the source table against the same value in the destination table. They cannot be the same according to the error message

Comment: Also could you clarify if you want to copy the whole table or just the first row?

Comment: I have tried the codes kblox and rahul suggested. It didn't have any error popping up but its just that the row of data did not transfer to the missedQueue table. @Steve

Comment: i just want to transfer 1 row. where i call a queue number, when i press the skip button, the data related to the queue number will move to the missedQueue table

Comment: If you want to copy a single row you first fill _queue_, then Clone it in the missedQueue table, finally add a new row to the _missedQueue_ table passing the itemArray of the source row

Comment: can u show it in codes? sorry, i'm still not sure as i think that the codes i've written above is the way u're explaining and i just needed to change the missed queue to clone... @Steve

Comment: If @kblok is still reading he has posted an answer now deleted that should be correct now

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use [`DataTable.Copy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) method and copy the `DataTable`:

```
DataSet queue = DBMgr.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM queue");
DataTable missedQueue = queue.Tables[0].Copy();
```

Comment: the error is gone but the row didn't copy/transfer to the other table. How do i fix that?

Comment: @user8090359, that shouldn't be. is your source table have rows? have you checked it?

Comment: That should do the job @user8090359

Comment: @kblok i'm not sure why it's not working.. does it affect if missedQueue is already an existing table but its empty inside

Comment: I changed the example above, that should work for sure

Comment: @kblok this will copy the whole table while the OP code copies only a single row.

Comment: @Steve true, what are you thoughts @user8090359?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
DataSet queue = DBMgr.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM queue");
DataTable missedQueue = queue.Clone();
.
.
.
missedQueue.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
```